# Add SQL command into database as Text C# MVC

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller

I have an MVC application that receives error reports from my app, however when the app sends sql errors I get an error from my mvc application saying that its dangerous code, is there any way to overcome this and get it to insert the text into the field in the database?

error below:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (exStackTrace="...teProgram.(SQLiteProgram...").

Comment: have you tried to catch the exception, and insert the e.message into the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)